# Why is the lowest moment prefered in the method of moments estimator

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

In An Introduction to Mathematical Statistics by Bijma, Jonker and Van Der Vaart. It is stated (page 73) that: "In practice, we prefer the method of moments estimator given by taking j as small as possible." Here j was denoting the moment. However, it is not explained why. 
Is it because this would result in lower MSE? Or that it is usually easier computationally?

Comment: Consider a distribution with a finite first moment and infinite second moment. Certainly the first moment would be more suitable to use in computing an estimator, yes?

Comment: Yea, but consider a distribution with finite second moment and infinite first moment?

Comment: I'm afraid that is mathematically impossible :)

Comment: You are right :)